# Query works in Access but not in my program. Why?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have this query set up in my application to work for searching through my database. I put this query into Access and it works fine. However, when I put it into my program the table has 0 entries. Can you please help?

```
private async Task FilterDB()
        {
            List<string> Filter = new List<string>();

            if (CardNameCheck.IsChecked == true)
                Filter.Add("*" + CardNameBox.Text + "*");
            else
                Filter.Add("*");

            if (CardExpanCheck.IsChecked == true)
                Filter.Add("*" + CardExpanBox.Text + "*");
            else
                Filter.Add("*");

                OleDbConnection DBCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseLocation);
                await DBCon.OpenAsync();

                OleDbDataAdapter CardDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE Name like '" + Filter[0] + "' and Expansion like '" + Filter[1] + "'", DBCon);
                DataSet CardDS = new DataSet();
                CardDA.Fill(CardDS);
                DBCon.Close();
```

Comment: Which version of Access are you using?

Comment: I'm running access 2013

Comment: Put a `try` `catch` to see if there is an exception

Comment: I took out a try catch and stepped through it one by one it says it fills the dataset and it gets to the for (just after the snippit) just fine then it skips over because CardDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count = 0

Comment: I think it's the provider, try this instead: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=`

Comment: With that provider it now throws this exception. The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: Your system is 32 or 64bits?

Comment: Ok you have work to do, [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64) is the solution of that error, and with that solution it will works

Comment: Thanks! I'll let you know what happens :)

Comment: Oh quick question. I used 4.0 on my original pull of the database. Should I also change that to 12?

Comment: Okay well that fixed the error but it still says there is nothing in my dataset. :/

Comment: This is I use and it works but with Access 2007: `m_connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + m_dataBaseFile + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + m_dataBasePassword;`

Comment: Try to use `%` in your filters: `Name like '%" + Filter[0] + "%'`

Comment: Oh that is interesting I just started poking in the Locals and came across this 'DBCon.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' Probably wasn't setting off the exception because I ran it async.

Comment: Try with the provider: `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`

Comment: It goes away if I switch back to 4.0.

Comment: No, still comes back blank. hmm but the connection server version no longer has an exception in it.

Comment: For the not registered error you could try this: I encountered the same problem: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27835
If that doesn't work, you could try to go project -> build properties --> platform target --> 32bit 
                          And If you don't need the async or the dataset, when I used the datatable it worked fine for me, http://pastebin.com/2EMZm9mU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and modified it a bit. Works for me for the Access2003 .mdb format.

```
OleDbConnection DBCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=(k:\mydatabases\mydatabase.mdb");
DBCon.Open();  

// Create a select Command - you need System.Data.OleDb and System.Data for this

OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
// define the CommandText with two parameters @Filter1 and @Filter2
selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE Name like @Filter1 and Expansion like @Filter2";

selectCommand.Connection = DBCon;

// Create two string / VarChar Parameters - 
// the following is a standard I commonly use 
// for string/varchar; you might also use OleDbType.NVarChar
OleDbParameter param01 = new OleDbParameter();
param01.ParameterName = "Filter1";
param01.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
param01.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
param01.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
param01.SourceColumn = "Name";
// provide them with values - I used text boxes for input
// use '%' for like statement - if no parameter provided use single '%' only
if (txtFilter1.Text.ToString().Equals(""))
{
    param01.Value = '%';
}
else
{ 
    param01.Value = '%' + txtFilter1.Text.ToString() + '%'; 
}
// add the parameter to the SelectCommand
selectCommand.Parameters.Add(param01);

// same goes for the second parameter
OleDbParameter param02 = new OleDbParameter();
param02.ParameterName = "Filter2";
param02.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
param02.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
param02.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
param02.SourceColumn = "Expansion";
if (txtFilter2.Text.ToString().Equals(""))
{
    param02.Value = '%';
}
    else
{
    param02.Value = '%' + txtFilter2.Text.ToString() + '%';
}
selectCommand.Parameters.Add(param02);

OleDbDataAdapter CardDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
// tell the DataAdapter to use a SelectCommand
CardDA.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
CardDA.GetFillParameters();   // actually not sure if you need this but does no harm either
DataSet CardDS = new DataSet();
CardDA.Fill(CardDS, "TargetTable");
DBCon.Close();

foreach(DataRow row in CardDS.Tables["TargetTable"].Rows)
{
    // do something ;
}
```

Good luck!